# Window is closed while exporting documents and unable to switch to parent window

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I am testing on IE browser. After clicking the Export button in the child window, child window closed and save and open download pop up in IE. Thereafter, I have used robot class to switch to pop up and click save option to download the file as shown in the image. But after clicking I want to return to parent window but it is showing "Window closed" and unable to do so.
[image]

```
     String parent= driver.getWindowHandle();

    for (String child : driver.getWindowHandles()) {

        if(!parent.equalsIgnoreCase(child))
        {

        driver.switchTo().window(child);


        if(browser.equals("chrome"))
        {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Export')]"))).click();
        }
        else if(browser.equals("IE"))
        {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Export')]")));

            WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Export')]"));

            myRobot.DownloadFileInIEBrowser(driver, ele);   
        }
        }
    }
   System.out.println("current handles"+driver.getWindowHandle());
   driver.switchTo().window(parent);
```

---

```
 public class myRobot {

public static void DownloadFileInIEBrowser(WebDriver driver,WebElement ele) throws AWTException, InterruptedException
{

    Robot robot = new Robot();
   //get the focus on the element..don't use click since it stalls the driver          
    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(ele).perform();

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.contextClick(ele).build().perform(); //right click on focus element
    Thread.sleep(5000);



    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);         
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }
   robot.delay(2000);
   /*robot command to move cursor to dialog pop up window
    * Ctrl+F6 pressed to move cursor to pop up dailog window in IE while downloading
    * Three times Tab button is pressed to focus cursor on Save button
    * Hit Enter again to save file
    */
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F6);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F6);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   {
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
   }
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First - by my own experience it take some time to `getWindowHandles()`.

Second - better to `getWindowHandles()` as `ArrayList`.

Third - switch to WindowHandle instead of parent.

```
ArrayList<String> winHandles = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
Thread.sleep(500);
driver.switchTo().window(winHandles.get(1));
// driver.switchTo().window(winHandles.get(0));
```